# Easy way to run python script in blender python console?

Tags: python, scripting

When I press "run script" with a python script in the Text Editor, it runs, but seems to spawn some new invisible python interpreter. I'd like it to run in the Python Console that I already have open. Is there a way to do this?

As it stands now, I'm copying and pasting from the Editor to the Console, which sure is tedious.

Comment: http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?312821-Run-Script-in-PyConsole-%28Menu%29&s=c69ef95a729a45ad03c6a2a7d67d176e  There may be some more recent versions, and IIRC @zeffii has something similar too.

Comment: Another [addon](https://bitbucket.org/pink-vertex/blender-scripts-and-addons/src/1b5ef8c552532462496bab0bc2582ed3f79cbbd2/development_console_utils.py?fileviewer=file-view-default). Note, that the blender python console uses [InteractiveConsole](https://docs.python.org/3/library/code.html#code.InteractiveConsole). You might have a look at `scripts/modules/console_python.py`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In Blender 2.80 and higher, you can use `as_module()`.

[image: Blender Python Console module example]

In the above example, an unsaved text editor shows this code:

```
def myTestFunc():
    print('This is my test function, running')

print('This is my test module, running')
```

Then, in the Blender Python console on the left, you can import this:

```
myModule = bpy.data.texts[0].as_module()
```

**Note** that since this is my *only* text file, I've used `texts[0]` to reference it.  If you had multiple, you would reference by name, such as `texts["Text"]` or similar.

**Note** that anytime the source code changes, you will have to re-run the `as_module()` command again to pick up the changes.

Finally, I can call functions from the module I imported, like so:

```
myModule.myTestFunc()
```

This uses the variable name that was assigned by the `as_module()` line, and looks for a named function within that module to call.

Comment: oh I love you.. a one-liner and so simple..

Comment: This is a good answer, but kind of a pain in the butt to need to keep running the as_module command.  I can't believe that they don't provide a "Run" button to run the script in the context of the interactive python interpreter!

Comment: @uglycoyote You might know this already, but in the Python console you can press the up-arrow key to recall prior commands, so you don't need to type it out each time.

Comment: I am looking for something like `from myModule import *` and I found a solution: `globals().update(vars(myModule))`

Answer (score 3):

In the text editor, make sure that the code you want to run is callable (f.e. make it a function). Name the text datablock `something.py`). Now you can use `import something` in the console, and call `something.yourfunc()` on it.

Comment: Sadly, this appears not to work anymore in Blender 2.80.

Comment: It appears that someone wrote a new answer about this ;-) Thanks @emackey

Answer (score -3):

In Blender go to Window and select toggle system console. Do this after "run script"