# Open Blender GUI from .py script

Tags: python

Can I open GUI window from `bpy` module and control scene from script?

Example:

```
import bpy
bpy.context.window_manager.windows["Default"].open()
```

Comment: @batFINGER i just want open Blender window from .py script in Linux and use same `bpy` in script and in window (blender builded as module already)

Comment: Suggest changing title of q to "Open GUI window from bpy built as python module".  Going by _This is mainly limited to features which can be usable in background mode, so you cant for instance do OpenGL preview renders._ from https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/User:Ideasman42/BlenderAsPyModule my guess is you can't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Blender built as a python module does not support a gui interface, it's runs as if blender was started in background mode. You can verify this by checking the background value

```
>>> import bpy
>>> bpy.app.background
True
```

If you are working on an addon, you can edit the scripts and then  disable/enable the addon to re-load the changes in blender. You may also want to look at the notes on [remote debugging using eclipse](https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Doc/Tools/Debugging/Python_Eclipse).

You can open a text file in blender and run it as a script, you can reload the file after changes and then run it again. You may find the addon I link to in [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/51159/935) helpful, the other answer there shows how to run a script straight from the file in blenders python console.