# Text Editor Scripts not available in the Python Console - but are available to scaling drivers

Tags: python, scripting

**Summary - Background**

- Created a text **drivers.py** file in Gedit
- Opened **drivers.py** in Blender Text Editor
- Selected [**x**] Register

**Summary - Issue**

- The scripts are available to my scaling drivers

  - No problem there
- When I try to run a test value in the python console I get the error

  - **NameError: name 'driver_Combo' is not defined**

**Summary - Question**

Do I need to do something to make the (external) scripts available in the Python Console ?

**Full Details**

Just recently started learning Blender.

I am using driver scripted expressions for **[ Transform ]** **[ Scale ]** of objects.

I was creating (and testing) scripts in the Python Console:

- all good with achieving my driver scaling
- scripts created in Python Console were not being saved with my .blend

Now I have moved them into the text editor:

- Created a text **drivers.py** file in Gedit
- Opened **drivers.py** in Blender Text Editor
- Selected [**x**] Register

This is the content of **drivers.py**

```
import bpy  
from math import degrees, radians  
from math import pi  
from math import sin  

# def function 
def driver_Combo(time):  
   radius = max(abs(sin(radians(time))),abs(sin(radians(time+90))))  
   if time > 360:  
      radius = 0  
   return radius  

# add function to driver_namespace 
bpy.app.driver_namespace['driver_Combo'] = driver_Combo
```

I'd like to have the scripts available in the Python Console to test values.

How do I make the scripts available ?

Thanks.

Comment: Try `from drivers import driver_Combo` in the py console.

Comment: 100%. Make that an answer and I'll accept your solution. Thank you very much.

Comment: A beautiful example of: **"Blender: You'll get it when you get it.**" Going from _W.T.F. ?? annoyance, lots of searching that offers no help, mild-headache_ to _Lights On - Ah Ha !_

Comment: Yes it's like that.

Comment: [This](http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/51159/935) may interest you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All good, you have the file "drivers.py" (correctly with the py extension) registered already you can simply

```
import drivers
drivers.driver_Combo(..
```

or

```
from drivers import driver_Combo
```

in the py console

Comment: Thanks. For any other users who arrive here searching for the same issue, check out this answer for a great way to simply run a bunch of `import` or other statements in a startup file - for example - OnLoad.py: **2 or 3 line text-block** http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/51078/34249