# Run a python script before console

Tags: python, scripting, command-line

When I launch blender with `-P` and `--python-console` together like this

```
blender -b -P my_script.py --python-console
```

my script is loaded after I exit the python console.  How can I run it before the python console shows up? 
Or can I make it run right after the console starts?

Comment: I think that is the way blender is setup to work. [This answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/51159/935) might help, it links to an addon that makes it easy to run scripts in blender's gui python console and the same technique [`exec(compile(text))`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#compile) can be used to run a script from the cli console.