# Is there a command port in Blender?

Tags: python, scripting

Is there a command port in Blender? 
In Maya or Max you can use a server that runs in the background of the application and evaluates a command if it receives any, It does not freeze the application but just stays there and waits for something to do.

Is there something like this in Blender?
regards.

Comment: Related : https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/101772/29586

Comment: This hack with reading and writing to some temporary file is kinda a workaround, but it' very dirty and there are problems with potential read/write operations at the same time.

Comment: Related : https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/41533/how-to-remotely-run-a-python-script-in-an-existing-blender-instance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, so there's apparently no command port in Blender. I needed one, so I've created an addon that implements this functionality.
It can be found on github:

- [Sources](https://github.com/p4vv37/blender_command_port)
- [Release](https://github.com/p4vv37/blender_command_port/releases/)

I hope, that someone else will find it useful, or worthy of improving, I'm open for ideas

Comment: As a Stream Deck XL user, I'm really happy for you taking this up. For better publicity, you should consider putting it up on Blender Market and making a post for it on Blender Artists in the Released Scripts forum. That way, you might easily get some help developing it further. https://blenderartists.org/c/coding/released-scripts-and-themes/50

Answer (score 0):

Up top, select **Scripting** from the view drop-down box.
Down at the bottom you will now see a console window, that allows you to type in commands.

[image: scripting]

Comment: Thanks, I know about it but this is not what I'm looking for. 
With command port, you can e.g. send commands directly from an external editor, or create some batch utilities or tools like "send to X" that operate on an opened application, so this is not a substitute for it.