# Run script through Python without polluting namespace?

Tags: python

How can I use the Python API to run a Python script, exactly as if it were either opened with `.use_module=True` or run with or `bpy.ops.text.run_script()`?

I don't think the the [existing answers](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/51074/how-to-run-a-python-script-external-to-blender-to-run-bpy-commands-in-blendersp) are about the same question, because I think the use of `exec()` will necessarily pollute the namespace/`globals`/`locals` it's given, likely clobbering existing names. It also seems to have trouble with imports.

Things I've tried:

- `exec(compile(), {}, {})`: Doesn't handle imports of external modules correctly.
- `Text.as_module()` (followed by `.register()`): Doesn't set `__file__` correctly.
- `ops.script.reload()`: Doesn't seem to actually run user scripts.

Comment: Helo, are you running scripts from the command line ?

Comment: @Gorgious I'm actually running them from another script, hence why clobbering `globals()` is unacceptable. For now I'm just switching the context area type to use `ops.text.run_script()`, but that's a bit dirty, so hopefully a better solution is possible.