# How to execute a python script inside execute(self, context) in operator class?

Tags: python

I have a simple python script moveobj.py

```
import bpy
for obj in bpy.data.objects:
    obj.location.x += 5
```

I want to execute this script in

```
class Translate_OT_Col_to_New_Location(Operator):
    bl_label = "TranslateColNewLoc"
    bl_idname = "object.translatecol"
    bl_description = "TranslateColNewLoc"
    

    def execute(self, context):
        execute python script moveobj.py here, is it possible?
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Put it into a function...? and then just run the function in the execute method.

Comment: As the python script will be updated by new content and its codes may differentiate from time to time. So I only need to execute a python script.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/51074/how-to-run-a-python-script-external-to-blender-to-run-bpy-commands-in-blendersp Got an answer from above.