# How to create a new blend file / project and run code in it

Tags: python

I would like to know how to execute code in a blend file / project using Python.

Comment: Go to the *Scripting* workspace, there you can create a new text data-block, paste and run the code: (https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/194425/107598). If you want to use this code interactively in Blender's Python console have a look here: [Easy way to run python script in blender python console?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/50487/107598)

Comment: Hi. I've edited my script. It now fully *runs* a imported script in a new blend.

Answer (score 3):

## Edit

Script now automatically runs in new blend.

---

### Recap summary of what this script does:

- Creates new blend file.
- Imports stated script.
- Replaces default `3D Viewport` window to `Text Editor` window.
- Assigns imported script to active `Text Editor` window.
- Automatically runs imported script once `Text Editor` window is active.

```py
import bpy

bpy.ops.wm.read_homefile(app_template="")
bpy.ops.text.open(filepath=str("D:\Blender\Scripts\external_script.py"))

for window in bpy.context.window_manager.windows: 
    for area in window.screen.areas:
        if area.type == "VIEW_3D":
            area.ui_type = "TEXT_EDITOR"
            area.spaces[0].text = bpy.data.texts["external_script.py"]
            with bpy.context.temp_override(window=window, area=area):
                bpy.ops.text.run_script()
            break
```